# Prove that if $\sqrt2$ is a positive number whose square is $2$, then $\sqrt2 \le \frac32$

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that in an ordered field, if $\sqrt2$ is a positive number whose square is $2$, then $\sqrt2 \le \cfrac32$ (without using numerical approximations).

I'm not even sure what the question is asking. I'm very new to real analysis but I think this question is asking to prove that the idea of $\sqrt2 \le \cfrac32$ follows the order axioms. On the other hand, I may be entirely wrong.

Please someone explain the brain thought and the steps to the proof!

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $\sqrt2 > \cfrac32$. Then $2\sqrt2 > 3$. Square: $8>9$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $y^2\gt x^2$ we have $(y+x)(y-x)=y^2-x^2\gt 0$

Now if (*) $y+x\gt 0$ this implies $y-x\gt 0$ or $y\gt x$

In your case you are given $\sqrt 2\gt 0$ and you know $\frac 32\gt 0$ so you can use (*) with $\sqrt 2+\frac 32$

I put this solution up because the first two posted don't highlight where the condition you are given about $\sqrt 2$ comes in.

Comment: Thank you . It is clearer now